# Image won't show in renders

Tags: rendering, image

I use images as planes(drag and drop), but they won't show up in either Evee or Cycles.

How can I make images show up in render?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drag and drop, do you mean you drag and drop a picture from your file explorer to Blender's viewport? If I remember correctly it doesn't crate a mesh plane but an image empty, which can't be rendered.

If you want to import images as planes, use the addon conveniently named "import images as planes". It is shiped with Blender, you just need to enable it in the preferences. Then use the penu File → Import → Images as planes. When navigating in Blender's file explorer, you can open the sidebar and play with the import options, like the shader used for import, as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>NumPad 7</kbd>. You might be on an "upside-down position" that is why it is hidden.